# Lua reverse hexadecimal encryption

Tags: lua

The following code I have takes a value and converts it into a hexadecimal string.

But how could I make a function that can reverse this and turn the hexadecimal encrypted string back to its original state?

```lua
local b = "Auth-+-ST4FF"
local a = ""

b:gsub('.', function(b)
    local hex = string.format('%x', b:byte()):upper()
    a = a .. ('0'):rep(2 - #hex) .. hex
end)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two simple functions for that task:

```
function encode(s)
    return (s:gsub('.',function (x) return string.format('%02X',x:byte()) end))
end

function decode(s)
    return (s:gsub('..',function (x) return string.char(tonumber(x,16)) end))
end
```

For a faster version of these functions, use predefined tables for the conversion between bytes and their hex representations:

```
local Encode={}
local Decode={}
for x=0,255 do
    local s=string.char(x)
    local h=string.format('%02X',x)
    Encode[s]=h
    Decode[h]=s
end

function encode(s)
    return (s:gsub('.',Encode))
end

function decode(s)
    return (s:gsub('..',Decode))
end
```